# Is it possible to exclusively target touch input devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, touch

I made an hover effect that would work well on mouse/keyboard interfaces but not so ideally with touch interfaces. I would like to target touch interface devices with some kind of media query or something that sets the touch input devices away from desktop style devices.

I would have used the screen size media queries but there are tablets whose sizes overlap with those of laptops. Is there a way to target touch interface devices with JavaScript or pure CSS or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `pointer` `media` query:

```css
div {
  padding: 8px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

@media (pointer:fine) {
  div:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: red;
  }
}

@media (pointer:coarse) {
  div:active {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Hover me on PC</div>
```

The `hover` property is defined only for those devices which has mouse(fine cursor);

Or you can apply different property for touch screens using
`@media (pointer:coarse)`

Answer (score 1):

You can sense if a device is a touch one by looking at some capabilities.

For example, the media query on hover tells you whether the device understands 'proper' hovering.

Here's a simple snippet to demonstrate:

```css
.hov:hover {
  color: black;
}

@media (hover: hover) {
  .hov:hover {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hov">Hover over me</div>
```

However, you may want to think through exactly which capabilities you want to test for, remembering that some devices may have both touch and mouse actions.